# Can i use a USB Headphone on an Audio interface with an USB to 3.5mm Adapter?

Tags: audio

So I recently bought the RAZER V2 Kraken 7.1 and it has a USB kabel. I want to use it on my interface with an adaptr that i bought and it isnt working. Am I doing something wrong or can't it work like this?

Answer (score 0):

USB and analog audio are two different things. I'm not sure what adapter you got, but I'm guessing that is has a purpose other than what you think.

The USB headphones are their own audio device. Your computer does not even need a sound card if you are using USB headphones. However, your computer MUST have a USB port. So you cannot use these headphones with a phone or MP3 player.

So, plug the USB cable of your headphones into one of the USB ports on your computer, wait for the software/drivers to install, and listen to some sweet tunes.